# IE7 - trying to place two adjacent divs in a button tag

Tags: css, html, button, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to style 2 divs in a button tag (1 div will hold an icon & another a descriptive text, please note I can't change the html tags).
In IE7, the 2 divs in a div sit side-by-side whereas the same 2 divs in a button tag sit 1 below the other.
Is there something specific with a button tag to arrange the dive 1 below each other and can it be overridden by any IE7 hacks or css tricks ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        button {
            display:block;
            float:left;
            clear:none;
        }
        .div1 {
            border:1px solid red;float:left;
        }
        .div2 {
            border:1px solid red;float:left;
        }
        .div3 {
            border:1px solid cyan;float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button><div class="div1">div1</div><div class="div2">div2</div></button>
<div class="div3"><div class="div1">div1</div><div class="div2">div2</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried clear: both;?

Comment: I see what the problem is, but the only thing I can think of is to give the button an explicit width, large enough to let the divs sit side by side. Is that an option? Oh, and you don't need `display:block`, because it's already floating.

Comment: Assign widths to your elements. because you are floating the elements as Mr_Lister stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this
in IE7 width is compulsory

```
          button {

        float:left;
        clear:none;
        width:80px;
    }
        .div1 {
            border:1px solid red;float:left;
        }
        .div2 {
            border:1px solid red;float:left;
        }
        .div3 {
            border:1px solid cyan;float:left;
        }
```

Comment: Fixing the width works, thanks, but fixing the width of the button might not be ideal as the length of the descriptive text might vary for different languages or is there another way to solve this too ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give the button a width, this is as close as I could come.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   button {
    /* no styles */
   }
   .div1 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid red;
   }
   .div2 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid red;
   }
   .div3 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid cyan;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button><div class="div1">div1</div><div class="div2">div2</div></button>
  <div class="div3"><div class="div1">div1</div><div class="div2">div2</div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now this is far from ideal, I can see that, but maybe it'll give you something to start with.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lister. My fault that I didn't mention in my initial post itself, that those div's can't be inline, because the 1st div is for an icon(I'm using background-image), which will require a width & height to be set on it, hence I couldn't go that route.